# Copy file between document libraries and update metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, file, copy

I'm using the following code to copy a file from one document library to another in the same site collection but I want to get the ID of the recently created file to update its metadata properties like the title and a lookup column called "RelatedID". Any support is appreciated. Regards.

```
function myFunction() { 
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile(context,"https://tenant/sites/MySite/MyDocumentLibrary1/file1.txt","https://tenant/sites/MySite/MyDcoumentLibrary2/file2.txt");
    context.executeQueryAsync(function (a, b) {
        alert("success");
    },
    function (a, b) {
        alert("failed");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as both files are in the Sam site collection, if you have the URL of both files, you can use `Web.GetFileByUrl` to get a reference to either the file you copied from or to.  From there, `File.Item` will get you a reference to the ListItem metadata.

```
var sourceFile = context.Web.GetFileByUrl("https://tenant/sites/MySite/MyDcoumentLibrary1/file1.txt");
var sourceItem = sourceFile.Item;
context.load(sourceItem);
var destFile = context.Web.GetFileByUrl("https://tenant/sites/MySite/MyDcoumentLibrary2/file2.txt");
var destItem = destFile.Item;
context.load(destItem);

context.executeQueryAsync(function (a, b) 
{
  var sourceId = sourceItem.ID;
  var destId = destItem.ID;

  //Copy metadata here

}, 
function (a, b) { alert("failed"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer, but I think it may help.  The following code copies all folders and files, including the metadata, recursively from one document library to another.  Please pay attention to the testing criteria and the purpose.

Testing criteria:

1. I have only tested it on SharePoint 2010/Windows 2008 R2 and 2019/Windows 2016
2. I only tested it on a single-server installation (no farm)
3. I only tested it on libraries within the exact same site
4. For 2010, I ran it from a `PowerShell -Version 2` command line because only PowerShell 5 was installed, and the snap-in for SharePoint 2010 doesn't support PowerShell 5.

Purpose:
The reason I wrote this was because I wanted to export a library larger than 0.5 GB from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019 without using a third party solution.  So, I had to break the library down into smaller parts.  Thus the reason for the `MaxRootFoldersToCopy` parameter.

Reference:
Code from [this site](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/copy-files-between-document-libraries-using-powershell-in-sharepoint.html) inspired my solution.

```
function Copy-SPFiles {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$false)]
  Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$SourceFolder,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$TargetFolder,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] [int]$MaxRootFoldersToCopy=[System.Int32]::MaxValue,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$false, DontShow=$true)] [switch]$BeyondRoot)

  Begin { Write-Verbose "Entering $($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)" }

  Process {
    Write-Verbose "Processing $($SourceFolder.Files.Count.ToString()) files"
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $SourceFolder.Files.Count; $i++) {
      Write-Verbose "Processing File: $($SourceFolder.Files[$i].Name)"
      $NewFile = $TargetFolder.Files.Add($SourceFolder.Files[$i].Name, $SourceFolder.Files[$i].OpenBinary(),$True)

      # Copy Meta-Data from Source
      for ($j=0; $j -lt $SourceFolder.Files[$i].Item.Fields.Count; $j++) {
        if (!$SourceFolder.Files[$i].Item.Fields[$j].ReadOnlyField) {
          if ($NewFile.Item.Fields.ContainsField($SourceFolder.Files[$i].Item.Fields[$j].InternalName)) {
            $NewFile.Item[$SourceFolder.Files[$i].Item.Fields[$j].InternalName]=$SourceFolder.Files[$i].Item[$SourceFolder.Files[$i].Item.Fields[$j].InternalName]
          }
        }
      }
      $NewFile.Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
    }
 
    #Process SubFolders
    Write-Verbose "Processing $($SourceFolder.SubFolders.Count.ToString()) folders"
    if ($BeyondRoot.IsPresent) { $Limit=$SourceFolder.SubFolders.Count }
    else {
      if ($MaxRootFoldersToCopy -lt $SourceFolder.SubFolders.Count) { $Limit=$MaxRootFoldersToCopy } else { $Limit=$SourceFolder.SubFolders.Count }
      if ($Limit -gt $SourceFolder.SubFolders.Count) { $Limit=$SourceFolder.SubFolders.Count }
    }
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $Limit; $i++) {
      Write-Verbose "Processing Folder: $($SourceFolder.SubFolders[$i].Name)"
      if ($SourceFolder.SubFolders[$i].Name -ne "Forms") {

        # Check if Sub-Folder exists in the Target Library
        $NewTargetFolder = $TargetFolder.ParentWeb.GetFolder($SourceFolder.SubFolders[$i].Name)
        if (!$NewTargetFolder.Exists) {
          $NewTargetFolder = $TargetFolder.SubFolders.Add($SourceFolder.SubFolders[$i].Name)
        }
        # Call the function recursively
        Copy-SPFiles -SourceFolder $SourceFolder.SubFolders[$i] -TargetFolder $NewTargetFolder -MaxRootFoldersToCopy $MaxRootFoldersToCopy -BeyondRoot
      }
    }
  }

  End { Write-Verbose "Exiting $($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)" }
}

Clear-Host
$Installed=Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" }
if ($Installed -eq $null) { Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" }

$VerbosePreference="Continue"
$SourceWebURL="http://<source site>"
$TargetWebURL="http://<destination site>"

$SourceWeb=Get-SPWeb -Identity $SourceWebURL -Verbose:$false
$TargetWeb=Get-SPWeb -Identity $TargetWebURL -Verbose:$false

$SourceLibrary="<source library name>"
$TargetLibrary="<target library name>"

$SourceFolder=$SourceWeb.GetFolder($SourceLibrary)
$TargetFolder=$TargetWeb.GetFolder($TargetLibrary)

Copy-SPFiles -SourceFolder $SourceFolder -TargetFolder $TargetFolder
```